# 404 Error page for existing page due to windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis-7

My website is redirecting to 404 error page when the page actually does exist. My website is set up so that it uses windows authentication. If the user does not have access, he/she is redirected to a page that tells them they have no access. If the user does have access then it takes them to another page. My website is set up on a 2008 server with IIS 7. The default document is Default.aspx, windows authentication is enabled and the rest is disabled, my website was working before I put in the security. I have also tried this with Anonymous Authentication. I also put to allow all users for now until I get this to work. I added in tracing to see what it was doing since we cannot debug on the server, so then I see that it is not getting the users' ID. So I do not know what I am missing. I cannot figure out why since this works perfectly on my local machine but not on the local server. I have researched this and I cannot come across anything else I can do. Also, this works when I run it on my local machine and I am using VS 2013.

To get the User's ID, I have used the following code:

```
un = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.ToUpper();
un = User.Identity.Name;
un = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

It crashes on the following line due to the user ID being 0.
I have searched YouTube videos that walk through setting up Windows Authentication and I even have it working on another application perfectly fine! This is frustrating and would really appreciate any help I can get. Please let me know if further details are needed.

The error I get is a 404 error

```
    Error Summary
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
Detailed Error Information
    Module IIS Web Core 
    Notification MapRequestHandler 
    Handler StaticFile 
    Error Code 0x80070002 
    Requested URL http://MyApp.com:80/Default.aspx 
    Physical Path D:\Sites\MyApp\Default 
    Logon Method Negotiate 
    Logon User XXX\bds
```

Comment: `un = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.ToUpper();` what is the value of this when you debug? also does it work locally..? if so then the problem is it's probably picking up the Remote machines domain/username do you have a login page..? I would personally do it from that using the `Request.Form["username"]` if you have a html control named `username` when having them enter he userid also read the following https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx

Comment: when it crashes, do you get a stacktrace then? If so, please add it to your question

Comment: @MethodMan When I debug locally, it works fine and it returns the correct userID. All those lines of code that I posted are examples of what I have used. I do not have a login page. I have another web app that doesn't use a login page and it works fine.

Comment: well post the code that works fine locally and test it remotely it's probably picking up the Remote Machines UserId.. what if you did something like this will it work 
`WindowsIdentity identity = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity;`

Comment: I just posted the error I was getting. The code I posted was all working fine locally and it all gets the correct user id, including the code that you just provided as well. So it isn't picking up the remote machine's user id.

Comment: I just figured out that my site wasn't working due to having the new ASP.NET ScriptManager. I just recreated my site and decided to leave that out, then it worked. Now the new problem is that the ScriptManager had a bundle for my CSS. Now I have to recreate my CSS.